# Why is it that I can't assign values to member variable of structures outside functions?

Tags: c, initialization, variable-assignment

I can't change variable value outside functions.
this code below throws up an error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student{
   unsigned int age:3;
};


struct student student1;
student1.age=8;/*this line*/

int main( ) {

    student1.age = 4;
    printf( "student1.age : %d\n", student1.age );

    student1.age = 7;
    printf( "student1.age : %d\n", student1.age );

    student1.age=5;
    printf( "student1.age : %d\n", student1.age );

    return 0;
}
```

this doesn't throw error

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student{
   unsigned int age:3;
};


struct student student1;
/*student1.age=8;this line*/

int main( ) {

    student1.age = 4;
    printf( "student1.age : %d\n", student1.age );

    student1.age = 7;
    printf( "student1.age : %d\n", student1.age );

    student1.age=5;
    printf( "student1.age : %d\n", student1.age );

    return 0;
}
```

please explain why. Also, outside a function, it doesn't allow for me to change global variable's value once it's defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [assignment statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) can only exist inside a function, so as the system knows when to execute the statement. It's not allowed to reside in a file scope, only can exist in a block scope of a function.

To elaborate, in C (hosted environment) program execution starts from `main()` function and it ends when it reaches end of `main()`, or terminated programatically. In a typical environment, the control moves from `_start` to `main()`, then child functions, back to `main()` and finally back to `_start` for program termination. Thus, any statement residing outside any function block, would not have a chance to execute, rendering it practically useless. That's why run-time statements are not allowed outside a function block.

[Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)), on the other hand, is allowed in file scope. The computation happens at compile time and the initialization happens before the execution of `main()` - so this can be and is allowed.

Comment: same for the global variables?

Comment: @Ashen-1 Yes, Read up about initialization vs assigment.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
student1.student1=6;/*This line*/
```

is an assignment and need to be include into a function.
This means, it's not allowed to change a variable or struct outside a function.
It's only allowed to initialize the struct at global scope.

Comment: True, but a differentiation of assignment and initialization needs to be added here for more context.